# Menu Language like this one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, jquery-animate

I don't know if this is a "valid" question, so forgive me if it's not.
I wanted to make a language selector like the one in this webpage:

http://panicstation.pixelthrone.com/html/

I Inspected the source and see that it was make by [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) but I can't reproduce that.
Anyone knows how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be to use jquery :

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7ECR/41/
HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="active">EN</li>
    <li class="hidden">ES</li>
    <li class="hidden">FR</li>
    <li class="hidden">PT</li>
</ul>
```

CSS :

```
ul {
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-radius:3px;
    text-align:center;
    width:25px;
}
li {
    list-style-type:none;
}
li.hidden {
    display:none;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
}
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul').hover(function () {
        $('.hidden').stop(true, true).slideToggle(800);
    });
});
```

Comment: can you set the question to answered please

Comment: I will wait to see if anyone else would say something, I already voted, if no one else answers I accept your answer

Comment: I improved the answer, added borders like on your example site. See fiddle

Comment: for horizontal remove display:inline-block on li